# How to append incremental number to a column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I writing a query in sql that pulls data from multiple tables.
One of the columns is a combination of multiple columns and an incremental number that resets when the value changes.

Format: `column = user ID + location ID + _ + incremental value`
i.e.

```
user1loc1_1
user1loc1_2
user1loc2_1
user1loc2_2
user1loc2_3
user2loc1_1
```

Comment: Try the row-number function which allows you to partition it.

Comment: Please paste sample data and your query.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a persistent number or something generated on the fly - and may change if underlying data changes?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
concat(userId, locationId, '_',
       row_number() over (partition by userId, locationId order by userId)
       ) as column
```

This specifies an arbitrary ordering.  You can replace the `order by` expression with another column if there is another column that expresses the ordering you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  
[user ID] + [location ID] + cast( ROW_NUMBER() 
over (partition by [user ID], [location ID] order by [user ID], [location ID]) as varchar(10)) 
FROM Your_Table
```